# Microsoft Interop Error On Generating Graphs

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, com-interop

I have been working on a project which makes a lot of calculations and gives results as Excel file. When I try to visualize those results on Excel Graphs, I take an error message (HRRESULT: 0x800706BA). I see that error message on depending on chart type (for example when I use "xlColumnStacked", there is no problem. But When I change into something else, I take error message.). Whole process is being done inside of BackgroundWorker's DoWork Method. I tried to explain my point below:

Outside of BackgroundWorker, I introduced Excel app as below:

`Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();`

My Backgroundworker's DoWork Method starts with codes below:

```
        Workbook workbook = myapp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        Worksheet Category6 = workbook.Sheets[1];
        Category6 .Name = "Category 6";
        Worksheet Category5 = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Category6 .Name = "Category 5";
        Worksheet Category4 = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Category6 .Name = "Category 4";
        Worksheet Category3 = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Category6 .Name = "Category 3";
        Worksheet Category2 = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Category6 .Name = "Category 2";
        Worksheet Category1 = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Category6 .Name = "Category 1";
        Worksheet General= workbook.Sheets.Add();
        General.Name = "General";
        Worksheet Report = workbook.Sheets.Add();
        Report .Name = "Report ";`
```

Following lines format cells and inputs informations from calculations into Excel File's cells. Formatting file takes for about 2000 lines of codes including loops and if statements.

Finally here is my problematic area:

```
Shape Cat1 = Category1.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlColumnStacked, 64, 30, 400, 300);
Cat1 .Chart.SetSourceData(Category1.Range[Category1.Cells[4, 40], Category1.Cells[8, 41]]);
Cat1 .Chart.HasTitle = true;
Cat1 .Chart.HasLegend = false;
Cat1 .Chart.ApplyDataLabels();
Cat1 .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Category 1";
Cat1.Chart.SetElement(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType.msoElementChartTitleAboveChart);
```

Here is the libraries I used (I am giving libraries in case of conflict between libraries or selection of wrong codes) :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
```

Best regards.(edited in order not to violate posting rules)

Comment: 0x800706BA is RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE which is a very generic error that tells you the COM server (here the Excel process your code talks to) is not answering COM (through RPC) calls. There can be many causes such as process hang, timeouts, crashes, etc. It also can be caused by 3rd parties (extensions, XLL, macros, etc.) loaded into Excel. You can try to make Excel visible, see if it displays anything. Difficult to say more w/o a reproducing code.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have tried making Excel file visible. App created Excel file and ran codes perfectly until it reaches problematic line I mentioned above and crashed again. Aditional information I forgot to say that codes was written inside of backgroundworker's DoWork method. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Is your code running in process with Excel out-of-process? By crash I mean the COM server crashes (which is Excel here). An error reported is *not* a crash. Anything could be the problem. Like I say, difficult to say w/o reproducing code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example